# Bash script to move files

Tags: scripts

I'm a beginner and I need help.

I'm trying to make a script to move some files from one directory in another directory.
Before to create the script I tested the command and it was working:

```
mv /path/to/source  /path/to/destination
```

After I've made the script with `nano`:

```
#!bin/bash/
echo "mv /path/to/source  /path/to/destination"
```

I've made the script executable with: `chmod +x file`
and then executed as `./file` but the following error appears:

```
bash: ./move.sh: /bin/bash/: bad interpreter: Not a directory
```

I tried and with `sudo ./file` and bash file but it’s not working.

I'm using Ubuntu installed with VirtualBox.

Comment: You should take a look at the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Answer (score 23):

That's because you used `#!bin/bash/` and this is wrong. The right way is:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

This is called a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) and it tells the shell what program to interpret the script with, when executed.

Another thing: the absolute path for bash interpreter in Ubuntu is `/bin/bash`, not `bin/bash/` or something else. You can check this using `which bash` command.

And another thing, but probably you know this: the following line:

```
echo "mv /path/to/source /path/to/destination"
```

will only display a text message with `mv /path/to/source  /path/to/destination`. To really move files use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

That is how your script should look like.

Comment: fyi, Ubuntu has historically packaged a crappy version of the incredibly useful [`which` command](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/which1.html). It's worth the manual install to get the [gnu which](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/which/).